# Online secure password management application

Tags: password-management

I am looking for an online password management application.
In our organisation, we have several accounts with various online services (AWS, Flickr, Google, online accounting, various hosting companies etc...)

I would like one place to have these stored, securely, so that if an employee left, or is off on holiday, we don't lose all of our login details.

Obviously security is an issue- so would need a reputable company.

I have used keepass for the offline world, but again, this is limited to one pc (i could share the db across the network i guess, but it's not ideal!)

Can anyone suggest such a service?

Comment: What if an employee would change password and forget to update it in the app? I think that's likely to happen.

Comment: @whitequark Still better to have the password stored somewhere. If that employee changed the password and forgot to update the database he/she would likely also forget to tell others.

Answer (score 1):

You could use on-the-fly generation of passwords, based on a master password that all employees know?
http://www.angel.net/~nic/passwdlet.html
But this doesn't give you a stored list of accounts&passwords, it only provides 1-click password entry.

A better solution would be KeePass or [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/downloads), stored on a DropBox share that all relevant computers are signed into.

In any case, you need a plan for what to do when employees leave - will you change the password for all the shared accounts?

Comment: I like 1Password, since it will automatically pick up password changes in the browser.  This should help keep the password list up to date.  1Password, and I assume KeePass, will also work fine on a shared network drive instead of dropbox.  This limits its use to only computers on the internal network, which could be good or bad depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Lastpass](http://lastpass.com/) seems to be the most popular (and controversial, as all online password managers are), and allows sharing passwords with other Lastpass users.

Of course, there are major security concerns with online password management, so I would try to find an alternative solution first. Flickr has email uploading right? Just share the email address. Your social network accounts can be shared securely using [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com) by adding other people by email address. Most hosting companies allow multiple FTP logins, so you can generate a different one for everyone.